# Geometry to Shapefile

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, geometry, vb.net

From importing the shapefile to postgis, its geometry is added to the database postgresql. The question, how can I load the shapefile in the Visual Basic.Net using the geometry in the database ?

Comment: By one of many interfaces to SQL exposed to VB.Net

Comment: That's not very helpful, if you could name a few that would help more. I know there are a few PSQL interfaces, each one having benefits and issues... perhaps you could list a few with descriptions and links for the OP to make an informed decision. Now *that* would be helpful. I too would be interested to see a discourse on interfaces, for academic reasons. I personally use ESRI SDE for PostgreSQL so don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [nPGsql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/) for this in C#. The geometry is fetched in either [WKB](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/general_topics/wkb_representation.htm) or [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format and some manipulation has to be performed to get these representations into ESRI geometries. I did encounter some problems with string lengths with very large polyline/polygon geometries, so if you have or are expecting very large geometries you may want to use a different database interface.

If you just want to convert back to shapefile then use [OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). Why write code for a tool that exists and works *very* well.